# Kivy Popup Text Wrapping Not Working As Expected

Tags: python, popup, label, kivy

I am trying to write a function that triggers a popup that has a message and a close button on the screen, however I can't seem to get the text to wrap properly. Currently the text stays within a 100 x 100 box (the default size).  The button does scale properly however, so I am confused as to what I am doing wrong.  Doing self.text_size = self.size seems to work fine in kv language but not in normal Python?

```
def default_popup(text: str, title: str = 'Warning') -> None:
    err_box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')

    err_txt = Label(text = text, font_size = 15)
    err_txt.text_size = err_txt.size
    err_box.add_widget(err_txt)

    close_button = Button(text = "Close")
    err_box.add_widget(close_button)

    err = Popup(title = title, content = err_box, size_hint = (0.6, 0.4))

    close_button.bind(on_release = err.dismiss)
    err.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CoreLabel` to calculate the size needed. Something like:

```
text_tmp = CoreLabel(text=text, font_size=15)
text_tmp.refresh()
err_txt = Label(text = text, font_size = 15, size_hint=(None, None), size=text_tmp.size))
```

Just make sure the properties of the `CoreLabel` are the same as the `Label`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `label.texture_size`. You just need to call `label.texture_update()` before you can use `texture_size`.

```py
err_txt.texture_update()
err_txt.text_size = err_txt.size
```

I would calculate the Popup size dependent on spacing, padding, text etc.:

```py
def default_popup(text: str, title: str = 'Warning') -> None:
   content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10, spacing=10)
   label = Label(text=text, halign='left', valign='center', markup=True)
   # to resize and get texture_size
   label.texture_update()
   close_button = Button(text='Close', 
                           size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(100, 45),
                           pos_hint= {'right': 1}
                           )
   content.add_widget(label)
   content.add_widget(close_button)
   popup = Popup(
            title=title,
            content=content,
            size_hint=(None, None),
            # auto calculate size 
            size = [a+b+c*2 for a,b,c in zip(label.texture_size, [dp(120),dp(120)], [content.padding[0], content.spacing])],
            auto_dismiss=True,
        )
   close_button.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
   popup.open()
```

Hope you can use it for your purpose.